# quickblox video and message chat on same view ios

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox, videochat

Hi i am want to chat and video option in same view everything is ok, i merged both code for video and chat implement in chat sample code.here only one issue only

```
  [QBChat instance].delegate = self;
```

create problem if i write it on viewwillappear for chat video working perfect but chat message not received

if i write it on method where i make a video call then both user must be click on video call button then call receive otherwise not and after call chat message not received

i am stuck here please tell me where i am wrong
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi waseem, If you solve this issue, please share it...

Comment: yes i solve problem is in ChatService class Qbchat delegate set and implement i remove it and write code in my own class for both chat and video call and not used ChatService class :-)

Comment: could u share that files....